# Magnolia CMS: form processors dependency

Tags: forms, magnolia

### In short

Is it possible to set dependencies between the form processors?

---

### In details

[Magnolia CMS has a form module](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Form+module) providing the ability to add custom form processors.

This system allows you to hook a class to the form's submission, in order to do whatever you want with the data sent through the form (i.e. send an email, save data to a Database, or else).

I would like to be able to configure/program my processors such as after form submission:

- start `processor A`
- if `processor A` completes successfully then start `processor B`
- then if `processor B` completes successfully then start `processor C`
- and so on...
- BUT if any of the processors does **not** complete successfully, the next processors will NOT be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All processors configured under the engine are executed in order in which they are specified.
If/when one processor doesn't complete successfully, have it throw `FormProcessorFailedException`. This will stop processing of the chain and prevent other processors (those positioned behind said one) to be executed.